# How to separate POCO layer from Entity Framework layer and still be able to add business logic to objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, n-tier-architecture

*I've seen a lot of these types of questions on here but they are either unanswered, not quite the same question that I am asking or the detail I need.*

I have included a screenshot of my project below for a high-level reference view of things.

1. In my "Sample" solution, I currently have a project called `Sample.Data.Model` that contains an edmx file of my database-first model.
2. **[Following the steps in this MSDN walkthrough,](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx)** I then moved the auto-generated POCO classes into a separate project and called it `Sample.Data.Entities`.
3. I then referenced the `Sample.Data.Entities` project in my `Sample.Data.Model` project and fixed all the usings so my project builds successfully.
4. I will of course need to add to the POCO classes so I added a `PartialClasses` folder in the `Sample.Data.Entities` project for my partial classes.

And then this is where I get lost.  In smaller (non n-tier projects) my edmx file and partial classes where in the same project so I could just add my class object related methods in my partial class files like this:

```
namespace Sample.Data.Entities
{
    public partial class User
    {
        public string FullName 
        { 
            get 
            { 
                return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName); 
            } 
        }
    }

    public User GetUser(int userID)
    {
        using (var dc = new ProntoEntities())
        {
            return (from u in dc.Users where u.ID == userID select u).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

And then in MVC project I could just do something like this...

```
User user = new User();
user = user.GetUser(1);
```

OR

```
User user = new User();
user.FirstName = "John";
user.LastName = "Smith";
user.Update();
```

However, I can't do that in this current setup because the partial classes know nothing about the Entities.

So, my question is, where in my current setup do I put the "queries" for data?

Also, if I'm going to make "ViewModels" for my MVC project, where should those go?  I would usually put those in the same project as my partial classes and edmx file as well.

**[Click to view larger version of image below](http://screencast.com/t/WTWCPfEz)**

[image]

Comment: Your main problem is that you try to implement _active record_ in an architecture that revolves around _persistence ignorance_. Entities should not have CRUD responsibilities. That's for the context and the `DbSet`s. Then you could have a service layer that knows the DAL (context + entities), and maybe knows a library with view models (or else contains the view models). The controller layer only communicates with the service layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, my question is, where in my current setup do I put the "queries" for data?

I think you should use the magical Repository Pattern.

For example: http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/

> Also, if I'm going to make "ViewModels" for my MVC project, where should those go?

Since viewmodel contain data what are connected to their views, i believe you don't need to put together with the Entities or their partial classes. If i were you, i just put to the Model folder in your MVC project.

Comment: thanks for the reply!! I'll look into the Repository Pattern but I was hoping for something a little more cut and dry. Also, I'm not crazy about putting my ViewModels in the MVC project because I like to return my data queries from the business layer as the ViewModels like this: http://screencast.com/t/n31t9rjU8HBR

Comment: For further details please check out this one: https://github.com/Binjaaa/ServiceRegistry/blob/master/SRR.DataAccessLayer/Repositories/SRREntityTypeRepository.cs

You can mark the methods of the base repository as virtual, thus you can modify each of them at the current repository. For example UserRepository.

Comment: And for the viewmodels: http://sampathloku.blogspot.hu/2012/10/how-to-use-viewmodel-with-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: Ok, then for the "ViewModels" maybe my terminology is off.  I guess I'm more referring to just plain object Models.  Instead of returning the entire User object to the controller from the BLL, I'd prefer to return a model of just the properties the controller needs for passing to the view.  The ViewModel link was helpful, however.  That's probably a good idea for me to start using as well.

Comment: I ended up using the Repository Pattern and an <Entity>Manager for the business logic.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in using the open source [N-Tier Entity Framework](https://ntieref.codeplex.com/) which uses Entity Framework on server-side and generates the entire infrastructure for building an n-tier architecture based on WCF including an EF-like API on client-side. Have a look at the framework’s user guide and sample applications available for download on codeplex. The resulting solutions are highly customizable while providing guidance on where to put what.

Comment: Great resource suggestion - I'll take a look.